# adding dataframes to same csv with blank row in between

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
In [31]: df1
Out[31]:
        State  Score
0  Arizona AZ     62
1  Georgia GG     47
2  Newyork NY     55
3  Indiana IN     74
4  Florida FL     31
```

and

```
In [30]: df3
Out[30]:
  letter  number animal
0      c       3    cat
1      d       4    dog
```

I want to obtain a csv like this:

```
1       State  Score
2  Arizona AZ     62
3  Georgia GG     47
4  Newyork NY     55
5  Indiana IN     74
6  Florida FL     31
7
8 letter  number animal
9      c       3    cat
8      d       4    dog
```

I was able to obtain it by creating an empty dataframe, appending it to the first dataframe and then adding the second dataframe to the csv like this:

```
empty_df = pd.Series([],dtype=pd.StringDtype())
df1.append(empty_df, ignore_index=True).to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)
df3.to_csv('foo.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

but I am getting a warning that the function 'append' is getting deprecated and I should be using 'concat'.

I tried this with concat:

```
pd.concat([df1, empty_df], ignore_index=True).to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)
df3.to_csv('foo.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

but I am not getting the empty line between the 2 sets of data.

Comment: Since the columns do not match, it's a terrible idea to structure the saved data in this way. The tables should be saved as separate files.

Comment: i agree but they want it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) with [**`np.nan`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/misc.html) to create the empty row :

```
import numpy as np

empty_df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * len(df1.columns)], columns=df1.columns)

pd.concat([df1, empty_df], ignore_index=True).to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)

df2.to_csv('foo.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

###### # Output (in Excel):

[image]